# How to remove words starting with capital letter in a list of strings using re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex, list, cpu-word, python-re

I am using Python and I would like to remove words starting with a capital letter in a list of strings, using `re.sub`.
For example, given the following list:

```
l = ['I am John','John is going to US']
```

I want to get the following output, without any extra spaces for the removed words:

```
['am','is going to']
```

Comment: Where do you have problems with your code and where is it? Learning a programming language involves making a lot of errors - otherwise you'd end up asking every time a new problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
output = []
for sentence in l:
    output.append(" ".join([word for word in sentence.strip().split(" ") if not re.match(r"[A-Z]",word)]))
print(output)
```

output:

`['am', 'is going to']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import re

l=['I am John','John is going to US']
print([re.sub(r"\s*[A-Z]\w*\s*", " ", i).strip() for i in l])
```

Output

```
['am', 'is going to']
```

This is a regex that removes all words from a given string that starts with a capital letter in addition it will remove all spaces before and after the word.

Comment: You welcome. Happy to assist it will be appreciated if you can mark the answer and vote up.

Comment: Can someone also tell what regular expression to use for the below eg-   

I am trying to write a regular expression for this list:   

data= ["I am John. Jo is going to US", "Cathy will also accompany him to US."]    
I want to delete all the words that starts with an uppercase letter but it should not check the first word of every sentence ie, it should not check for I, Jo and Cathy.    

The output should be  

Output-["I am. Jo is going to", "Cathy will also accompany him to."]  

Thanks.